# new DNA sequencing technologies?

Tags: dna-sequencing

Last year I did my thesis in the field of a new method for DNA analysis. 
Which I think is very interesting although I cannot seem to find any new methods in this field especially the SMRT sequencing method.

Do you maybe know a new method(s) which are introduced for DNA research in the area of SMRT sequencing ?

Comment: You mean new sequencing technologies introduced since last year?

Comment: I think you expect the development of new technologies by far to fast. I am not even sure if new experimental ideas have been developed in this time, let alone made commercial.

Comment: This question is broad. Nobody knows what you have done in your thesis. Please explicitly mention what kind of analysis you are interested in. Research is always happening and there is always *some* development. Unless you provide specifics, your question may be put on hold.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I already have my answer :)

Comment: Yes, there's a new technique called Sanger sequencing. Have you heard of that? In other words, if you don't tell us what you know, how can we tell what you don't know?

Comment: Community edits to clarify, and votes to reopen, I'm too new on this particular site to help rep wise, but I think from the comments that the accepted answer is conformed by the O'P'er to be excellent, the O'P'ers meaning seems therefore to be now understood sufficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, which technique you worked on, but there are the so-called 'Next Generation Sequencing' methods. I think the oldest of that is a pyrosequencing technique called 454 sequencing (I think it is provided by Roche). However, this method is too expensive compared to even newer methods and the support will be stopped within the next months, as far as I know.

Furthermore, there are the Illumina and the ion torrent technique. Finally, there is SMRT sequencing of which some people say that this is even third generation sequencing. I think, this [paper](http://bmcgenomics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2164-13-341) provides a nice overview. And if you're interested in further reading, yet you know what to search for.

Comment: thanks for you comment, so there aren't any new techniques at the moment. I didn't work with them but i know every one of them and how they work. I worked on a new nanohole based single molecule sequencing technique

Comment: I'd recommend working on your question @pwghost even though it may well not get reopened.

Comment: @alan2here edited it :)

Comment: Sorry for being vague with my comment, I've found this frustrating enough myself so I do apologise for doing it as well. I think it's the word "new", could you narrow that down, perhaps to this and last for example?